# Add class to <body> if url has more strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

how can i  detect if URL has more strings and add an class
basically i want add a class if is home page or if is Inner Page

**example:**
 if the url is: https://example.com  => in body add "home-page"
and if the url is: https://example.com/2018/04/test.html or anything after .com  => in body add class "inner-page"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(url.indexOf('example.com') > -1){
        $("body").addClass("home-page");
    }
});
```

for inners is not working

Comment: What did you try for inners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your answer is that it will return true as long as the url contains "example.com". Thus you might want to check for the pathname instead :

```js
document.body.setAttribute("class", (location.pathname.length <= 1 ? "home-page" : "inner-page"))
    console.log(document.body.className);

//returns "inner-page"
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could user `document.location.pathname` to determine which class to assign like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var url = document.location.pathname;

    if(url === '/'){
        $("body").addClass("home-page");
    }
    else {
        $("body").addClass("inner-page");
    }
});
```